# Design suggestion required

Tags: android

I want to create an application in which
- Create a listener which listens for outgoing/incoming messages and calls
- UI is shown/hide based on listener results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shrini,

As dds stated, you will definitely need at least two `BroadcastReceiver`s. You will need one `BroadcastReceiver` for each incoming call and message that you want to respond to, and one for each outgoing one as well. A `BroadcastReceiver` may only capture one `BroadcastMessage` at a time. You will specifically need to capture the `Intent`s sent by the operating system and your `Application` will need to have the appropriate `Permission`s for each. That's just setting up the listeners.

Once the `BroadcastReceiver` has been called you will need to start an `Activity` for you UI and possibly a `Service` to do any other processing. In the cases of single-point events (like messages) an `Activity` is often enough. Calls, however, depend largely upon what you are doing. Since a call has two distinct events, in order to tie them together, many people prefer to use a `Service` just to hold and watch the call.

In order to best help you, I must inform you that your question is remarkably vague as to what you need to do. Does your custom UI display information about the calls? Does it allow the User to respond or change that information? What kind of messages is your app responding to? SMS? Email? IMs? These are important because each one has different considerations.

Given that the limitation of information provided here, I would recommend researching your topic by downloading and viewing some of the open source projects stored on Google. Here is a [Here](http://code.google.com/hosting/search?q=label%3aAndroid).

Fuzzical Logic

Comment: Thank you Fuzzy, I'm newbie android developer, basically I want to develop application like www.calljuggler.com in android. Hope this will give some idea

Comment: Shrini, Sorry I have been away for about a week. Calljuggler.com? Let me take a look and I'll leave a response tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

> Create a listener which listens for
>   outgoing/incoming messages and calls -
>   UI

To achieve this I think you need to use broadcast receivers to catch the `broadcast message` when any message activity is going on. You may need 2 in BroadcastReceivers , one for incoming and one for outgoing messages.

In the receivers you need to call your related Activity (your UI) to interact with the user. But note that you should not do any time consuming work in BroadcastReceiver since in BroadcastReceivers  are expected to be light weight and killed in 10 seconds after they are invoked. See Broadcast receivers at [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/04/multitasking-android-way.html)